# Accessing Properties Through Relationships in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have several models set up in a `Grandparent -> Parent -> Child` relationship, where each has a one-to-many relationship with the one beneath it.  The backend is set up through migrations using the default `created_at` and `modified_at` dates, relevant as that is what I'm trying to grab records by.

I currently have (names replaced):

```
$parent->child->where('created_at', '=', $date);
```

Through echo'ing it out I can verify that `$date` is correct when the where function is run, and matches records in the database.  My expectation based on documentation is that this should return a Collection.  When I attempt to iterate through it to get each instance of the model inside, however, I get errors saying I'm attempting to access properties of a non-object.  (Just trying to echo out the `created_at` date).

I also tried putting `->first()` after the original, with the assumption that it would spit out the first child as an object, that matched those pre-requisites, however it comes out null despite the collection not showing as null when similarly tested.

My question is, is there a way to get the `first()` approach to work, returning a single instance of the model?  Similar to:

```
$parent->child->where('created_at', '=', $date)->first();
```

This is my first time posting a question so if you need more info just ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having is due to the difference between:

```
$parent->child;
```

and

```
$parent->child();
```

The former (`$parent->child`) is a Collection of all the child objects, whereas the latter (`$parent->child()`) is the relationship query for the child objects.

The sneaky problem you've hit is that both support the `where()` method, but their parameters are a little different. The parameters you're using would work fine for the `where()` method on the relationship query, but they are not correct for the `where()` method on the Collection, which is what you're using.

You either need to switch to using the relationship query, or change your parameters to work with the `where()` on the Collection:

```
$children = $parent->child->where('created_at', $date);
// or
$children = $parent->child()->where('created_at', '=', $date)->get();
```

Note: the `where()` method on the Collection will filter the collection based on the field name ('created_at') being equal (== or ===) to the $date value. The third parameter will govern the strictness (default is strict (===), or use `false` for loose (==)).

Answer (score 1):

`$parent->child` returns the processed query as a collection. To add to the query with your `where` statement you will need to use the `child` method (which returns a query object), not the child property:

```
$parent->child()->where('created_at', '=', $date)->first();
```